# Implementation details of iOS 6 Safari Reader

Tags: ios, css, safari, typesetting

I recently upgraded my iPad to iOS 6, and surprisingly noticed that the Reader plugin in Safari works perfect in terms of typesetting. It now aligns both English and Chinese excellent, with both left and right hand sides aligned neatly. Which I believe didn't do in the previous versions.

So my question is does anyone have any idea how it was implemented? Any details or hints will be appreciated as I have been seeking a way of typesetting both English and non-English web contents. For English it is a bit easier using CSS like text-justify, but for non-English it is hard.

Thanks and regards,
Johnny

Comment: I can't for the life of me remember what this is called for some reason but if you check out the [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) videos there was one that thoroughly covered how to do this. (check out attributed strings and Core Text)

Comment: Looks like attributed strings and core text are for iOS native app development, the reader plugin might be implemented this way though, which unfortunately is not really web related.

Answer (score 0):

Check under

```
/Applications/MobileSafari.app/Reader~iphone.html
```

This is the path used in iOS 7 version of Mobile Safari, but I guess it should work on iOS 6 as well.

The same file is available via the SDK or the iPhone Simulator.